# Join multiple JSON strings in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, json, custom-controller

I have a requirement to display **Accounts-->child Accounts-->Tasks-->Child Tasks** in the JSON.

Here is my Apex code:

```
List<Account> accountRecordsList = new list<Account>(); 
List<Custom_Tasks__c> taskRecordsList = new list<Custom_Tasks__c>(); 

accountRecordsList = [SELECT Id,Name,parent_account__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Accounts1__r) FROM Account WHERE Id = '<some record id>'];
string strJSON = JSON.serialize(accountRecordsList); //Account and Child Accounts

 Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account pr : accountRecordsList){
            for(Account cpr : pr.Accounts1__r){
            if(cpr.id != null){
                accountIds.add(cpr.id);
            }
            }
        }
taskRecordsList = [SELECT id, name,account__c, (SELECT id, name,pse__Start_Date__c, pse__End_Date__c from Sub_Tasks1__r ) from Custom_Tasks__c where account__c in :accountIds];
string ptJSON = JSON.serialize(taskRecordsList); //Tasks and Child Tasks related to above obtained child accounts
```

Now, the requirement is to append ptJSON to the first obtained strJSON under child Accounts. Can anyone please let me know how to get this thing done.

/////Update with Gaurav Sharma's Solution////////////////

```
Public class AccountTaskWrapper{
    Account acc;
    List<Custom_Tasks__c> taskList ;
}

List<Account> accountRecordsList = new list<Account>(); 
List<Custom_Tasks__c> taskRecordsList = new list<Custom_Tasks__c>(); 

accountRecordsList = [SELECT Id,Name,parent_account__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Accounts1__r) FROM Account WHERE Id = '<some record id>'];


 Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account pr : accountRecordsList){
            for(Account cpr : pr.Accounts1__r){
            if(cpr.id != null){
                accountIds.add(cpr.id);
            }
            }
        }
taskRecordsList = [SELECT id, name,account__c, (SELECT id, name,pse__Start_Date__c, pse__End_Date__c from Sub_Tasks1__r ) from Custom_Tasks__c where account__c in :accountIds];

List<AccountTaskWrapper> ATWrapperList = new List<AccountTaskWrapper>();

Map<Id,List<Custom_Tasks__c>> taskListByAccountMap = new Map<Id,List<Custom_Tasks__c>>();

Map<id,Account> accountMapById = new Map<id,Account>(accountRecordsList);

for(Custom_Tasks__c task : taskRecordsList )  {
     if(taskListByAccountMap.containsKey(task.account__c)) { //Issue with this line as the logic isn't going into the condition and I am seeing nullpointer exception if i remove this if condition
        taskListByAccountMap.get(task.account__c).add(task);


}
else {
     taskListByAccountMap.put(task.account__c, new List<Custom_Tasks__c>{task});

}
}

for(Id accountId : taskListByAccountMap.keyset() ) {
    AccountTaskWrapper ATWrapper = AccountTaskWrapper();
    ATWrapper.acc =  accountMapById.get(accountId);
    ATWrapper.taskList = taskListByAccountMap.get((accountId); 
    ATWrapperList.add(ATWrapper);

}

String finalJSON = JSON.serialize(ATWrapperList);
system.debug('FinalJSON==>'+finalJSON);
```

Comment: Convert the JSON strings into a couple of `Map<String, Object>` via deserialization then navigate the container map to find the required "node" into which you add the child map. You can then re-serialize the JSON into a string if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a wrapper class which will hold both account and task list.
assign values to wrapper class instance  and then serialize that wrapper class.

```
//wrapper class  

Public class AccountTaskWrapper{
    List<Account> accountList;
    List<Custom_Tasks__c> taskList ;


}



// changes in main logic

//initialize a new instance of wrapper class
AccountTaskWrapper  ATWrapper = new ATWrapper();

//assign account and contact to wrapper instance
ATWrapper.accountList = accountRecordsList;
ATWrapper.taskList =  taskRecordsList ;


//serialize wrapper instance
String finalJSON =  JSON.serialize(ATWrapper);
```

---

logic to get task list by account

```
//logic to get tasklist by account

//wrapper class
Public class AccountTaskWrapper{
    Account acc;
    List<Custom_Tasks__c> taskList ;


}



//logic

List<Account> accountRecordsList = new list<Account>(); 
List<Custom_Tasks__c> taskRecordsList = new list<Custom_Tasks__c>(); 



accountRecordsList = [SELECT Id,Name,parent_account__c, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Accounts1__r) FROM Account WHERE Id = '<some record id>'];
//string strJSON = JSON.serialize(accountRecordsList); //Account and Child Accounts

 Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account pr : accountRecordsList){
            for(Account cpr : pr.Accounts1__r){
            if(cpr.id != null){
                accountIds.add(cpr.id);
            }
            }
        }
taskRecordsList = [SELECT id, name,account__c, (SELECT id, name,pse__Start_Date__c, pse__End_Date__c from Sub_Tasks1__r ) from Custom_Tasks__c where account__c in :accountIds];
//string ptJSON = JSON.serialize(taskRecordsList); //Tasks and Child Tasks related to above obtained child accounts

//define wrapper list
List<AccountTaskWrapper> ATWrapperList = new List<AccountTaskWrapper>();

//define map to store account with related task
Map<Id,List<Custom_Tasks__c>> taskListByAccountMap = new Map<Id,List<Custom_Tasks__c>>();

//convert accountList to map by id
Map<id,Account> accountMapById = new Map<id,Account>(accountRecordsList);



//iterate over tasks  
//group it by account

for(Custom_Tasks__c   task : taskRecordsList )  {
     if(taskListByAccountMap.containsKey(task.account__c)) {
        taskListByAccountMap.get(task.account__c).add(task);


}

else {
     taskListByAccountMap.put(task.account__c, new List<(Custom_Tasks__c>{task};

}



}

//assign wrapper instance and add to wrapper list

for(Id accountId : taskListByAccountMap.keyset() ) {
    AccountTaskWrapper ATWrapper = AccountTaskWrapper();
    ATWrapper.acc =  accountMapById.get(accountId);
    ATWrapper.taskList = taskListByAccountMap.get((accountId); 
    ATWrapperList.add(ATWrapper);
   
   



}


//serialize wrapperlist
String finalJSON = JSON.serialize(ATWrapperList)';
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I could able to get both the JSON under single JSON but is there anyway I can append the taskList under its related child Accounts?

Comment: to get taskList based on account.  you need to first prepare data based on account.   accordingly you have to modify wrapper class also to contain  single account with related task.   and finally serialize list of wrapper instance.  please check edited answer for sample logic.   i have not compiled the code so there might be some errors.

Comment: after updating my logic with the suggested solution, I am seeing the output as null under ATWrapperList. I could only fetch independent Tasks but not the ones which are related to Accounts. In the debug log, I could see that the accountId is coming as null from tasklistbyAccountMap. Could you please suggest any update here?

Comment: the issue is from taskListbyAccountMap which is throwing null pointer exception when we tried to fetch task related Account Ids. I could see that TaskRecordsList has tasks and its account values but in the map, i am seeing null. Could you please let me know how to resolve this error

Comment: sure.   i will try to replicate it as i have not run the code and it is just logic.   if it is possible  can you provide me your updated code of this logic   and debug logs  where we are getting error.

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggested code and the line where I am seeing the error. Could you please suggest any update here?

Comment: for the first time it is expected that  this condiiton will be false.       if(taskListByAccountMap.containsKey(task.account__c)) { //Issue with this line.   and it should go into else.       can you put system.debug('map' + taskListByAccountMap);   after for loop logic and confirm if you are seeing data in map or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128144/discussion-between-sfdcuser-and-gaurav-sharma).